# Parsing text using regular expression works with online tests but not this code

Tags: java, regex

I tried this regex in Java :

```
Pattern orderCheck = Pattern.compile("^([\\-\\+])?(created|title|price|creation)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
orderCheck.matcher(value).matches();
```

And oddly :

- created : **works**
- -created : **works**
- +created : **doesn't works**
- title : **works**
- -title : **works**
- +title : **doesn't works**
- etc..

The + result as a non validation of the regex, but I can't understand why.

Using this [online regex tester](http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/), it works perfectly, for all the values !

I also tried this variants, but unsuccessfully :

- ^[\-\+]?(created|title|price|creation)$
- ^[-+]?(created|title|price|creation)$
- ^(-+)?(created|title|price|creation)$
- ^(-|+)?(created|title|price|creation)$
- ^[-|+]?(created|title|price|creation)$
- ^(\-|\+)?(created|title|price|creation)$

What is the correct regex for my need? I can't see where I'm wrong.

Comment: Your pattern works for me. How are you testing this?

Comment: escape the `-` and it should work.

Comment: Like isbadawi, I find that your pattern works fine (though the backslashes on `-` and `+` aren't actually needed). I'm betting that `orderCheck.matcher(value)` doesn't actually start with the `+` that you think it does. Maybe it's being URL-escaped, to `%2B`? Or maybe *de*-URL-escaped, to a space?

Comment: @BartoszGrzybowski: The `-` *is* escaped. This is Java; after the first pass of backslash-processing, the OP's code creates a regex `^([\-\+])?(created|title|price|creation)$`.

Comment: You are right ruakh, the problem is the "+" that is escaped in the url !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. Maybe you forgot a space char at the end/begining of your value? Your pattern seems OK.

[image: test res]